# Loading nav bar in react router switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I load my header component, always, when i have conditional routing, with my other components

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Header />         
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
      <Route path="/products" render={() => <Product />} />
      <Route path="/company" render={() => <Company />} />
      <Route component={noMatch} />
      </Switch>
```

I want the header component to always render, and then use the switch to render my other components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your switch inside a component which includes the header, something like

```
<Grid container alignItems='flex-start' className='route'>
  <Grid item align='center' className='logo' xs={12}>
    <Header />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item className='content' xs={12}>
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
          <Route path="/products" render={() => <Product />} />
          <Route path="/company" render={() => <Company />} />
          <Route component={noMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

the router can wrap around that, or you can export this as a component and place it inside your router in another component